# SQL Server BigInt vs Decimal

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

I need to choose a data type for SQL Server( BigInt vs Decimal) on the basis of performance and querying (10 digit number)

Comment: Since you are only concerned with 10 digit number (max), you should go for decimal. Decimal wont loose fraction when doing division.

Comment: Are you pulling this value into app code? If so, what language?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need fractions, choose bigint. In your case it will be a byte smaller:

10 digit decimal is 9 byte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187746.aspx

bigint is 8 byte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187745.aspx

Plus, it is faster (it has no variable part, and it is an integer type, much faster processed by cpu).

Comment: Can i get any proper documentation showing BigInt is faster than Decimal?

Comment: Take for example a look here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3323/comparing-sql-server-datatypes-size-and-performance-for-storing-numbers/

Comment: @user_0, although one would think bigint would be faster than numeric/decimal, I recently ran some performance tests (large multi-million row join queries) to validate this theory for a non-functional user story.  There was no significant difference in performance with our application so we decided not to proceed with the change.  I would use bigint for new development, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with whole numbers then BIGINT will be a higher performance datatype because it won't have to deal with any rounding.

If you need decimal places you must use decimal